# Vite: dev server crashes with chunks larger than 500 kB after minification

Tags: vite

The problem seems to be zxcvbn:

`../public/vite-dev/assets/zxcvbn-V60ZPkbA.js    818.73 kB │ gzip: 392.12 kB`

My vite config looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';
import RubyPlugin from 'vite-plugin-ruby';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    RubyPlugin(),
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          // treat all tags with a dash as custom elements
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.includes('-')
        }
      }
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
      '@fa6path': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? path.resolve('/assets/font-awesome-6') : path.resolve('vendor/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome'),
    }
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
            return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  server: {
    watch: {
      // Exclude specific directories or files using glob patterns
      exclude: ['logs/**', 'tmp/**', 'node_modules/**', 'docker/'],
    },
  },
})
```

Does anyone have an idea how to increase the tolerated chunk size (NOT increase the warning limit)? The dev server crashes cause of this which is pretty annoying. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's because of this that the server crashes? Do you get an error message from the crash?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie If I remove it it runs smoothly. So I am quite sure about it.

Comment: With @GuillaumeBrunerie I really doubt that a size just a bit over 500k would crash the dev server. You would have to have a really restricted system to have that. Merely, I guess that the package contains some "bad code" in this regards, thus an error message or process exit code or something would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite provides a `chunkSizeWarningLimit`, but this is only to show a warning of the files that exceed the default `500kb chunkSizeWarningLimit`. In your case this is a big problem since you're saying that the dev server is crashing.

In your answer I'm not seeing any use of a split chunk plugin, these kind of plugins should split files so that they don't exceed the 500kb default `chunkSizeWarningLimit`. I suggest you try [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-chunk-split), its called vite-plugin-chunk-split and it should get rid of the issue.

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't want. I don't want to increase the warningLimit. Cause that doesn't get rid of the crashes at all. I'll try the plugin tho.

Comment: @temp I'm not saying that you should increase the warningLimit that would definitely not solve the problem. I'm only saying that one of the many chunk split plugins that exist for vite may solve the problem. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: Right, my bad. I tried it out but still can't figure out how to decrease the chunk size tho.

Comment: Adding: `chunkSplitPlugin()` to your `plugins` list in vite should do the trick. If the issue still persists then I'm not sure you might need to check the options of the plugin, and maybe as the other comments say (and I do think this aswell) "Are you sure it's because of this that the server crashes?".